# delete a sequence of days from a dataframe,

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe, where I want to excerpt a sequence of days from a specific year. I thought this would be often asked but did not find any similar question.

```
d=data.frame(doy=rep(seq(1,365, by=1),2),year=rep(c(1,2),730))
```

I am guessing it should be something like this, but I cant get to the actual solution.

```
d[-d$Year==1 & d$doy==c(205:233)],]
```

Thanks in advance.
Agus

Comment: perhaps `d$doy %in% 205:233`

Comment: Thanks, that works for selecting them,  to excerpt them, now i can add an ! infront of that to excerpt the selection from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d[d$doy %in% 205:233 & d$year == 2, ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this would completely solve the question: d[!d$doy %in% 205:233 & d$year == 2, ]